# Producing a batch message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Let's say there is a batch API for performing tasks **List[T]**. In order to do the job all the tasks needs to be pushed to kafka. There are 2 ways to do that :

1) Pushing List as a message in kafka
2) Pushing individual task T in kafka

I believe approach 1 would be better since i don't have to push the messages to kafka mutiple times for a single batch call. Can some one please tell me if there is any harm in such approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Kafka producer can batch together individual messages sent within a short time window (the particular config is `linger.ms`), so the cost of sending individual messages is probably a lot lower than you think.

Probably a more important factor to consider is how the consumer is going to consume messages. What should happen if the consumer cannot process one of the tasks, for example? If the consumer is just just going to call some other batch-based API which succeeds or fails as a batch, the a single message containing a list of tasks would be a perfectly good fit. On the other hand if the consumer ultimately has to process tasks individually then sending individual messages is probably a better fit, and will probably save you from having to implement some sort of retry logic in your consumer, because you can probably configure Kafka to behave with the semantics you need.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Tom :)

Comment: Does linger.ms and transactions work together? Or Can I define Exactly-once delivery of a batch in kafka?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Kafka v0.11 you can also use transactions in the producer to publish your entire batch atomically. i.e. you begin the transaction, then publish your tasks message by message, finally you commit the transaction. Even though the messages can be sent to kafka in multiple batches, they will only become visible to consumers once you commit the transaction, as long as your consumers are running in read-committed mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot Micheal :)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is the preferred method in Kafka so long as the entire batch should always stay together. If you publish a List of records as a batch then they will be stored as a batch, they will be (optionally) compressed as a batch yielding better compression, and they will be fetched by consumers as a batch yielding fewer fetch requests.

If you send individual messages then you will have to give them a common key or they will get spread out over different partitions and possibly be sent out of order, or to different consumers of a consumer group.